# How to escape ${} in Groovy String

Tags: groovy

I have a string S like `"${abc}"`,here `${}` is special expression, but I want to avoid the evaluation of the expression and match S with `"${abc}"` literally in Groovy.

I run `S.matches("\\$\\{abc\\}")` to match S with `"${abc}"`.  Because I think I need to escape $ { } using \. but it doesn't work.

Do do anyone know how to achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried using the Matcher e.g. `def matcher = s =~ /\$\{abc\}/` where s is your String value e.g. `def s = '${abc}'`?

Comment: Thank you, this is what I want

Comment: When using double quote strings `"` with `${}` expression inside them, the string interpolation will occur. When evaluating the string, Groovy will try to replace the placeholder expression (anything inside `${}`), with its value. Since you don't have **abc** variable defined, you'll get an error. You can find out more in the official [docs](https://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#_string_interpolation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what your problem is, but the following straight-forwards regex works just fine:

```
String s = '"${abc}"'
assert s ==~ /"\$\{\w+\}"/
```

Comment: I just want to know why `s.matches("\\$\\{abc\\}")` cause an error.

Comment: you should use `"` ONLY if you want to have your impression evaluated. For plain old strings you should use `'`

Comment: Thank you for your explaination